# why the state could not get the newest in flutter after change the state in reducer

Tags: flutter

I am get the flutter state in `buildView` function like this:

```
Widget buildView(ArticleListState state, Dispatch dispatch, ViewService viewService) {
  final articles = state.articles;
}
```

but the state could not get the newest, I am dispath to set articles in initial function in `effect.dart` like this:

```
Future _onInit(Action action, Context<ArticleListState> ctx) async {
  ArticleListState articleListState = ctx.state;
  List<int> ids = articleListState.articleIds;
  List<Item> articles = new List();
  for(final i in ids){
    Item article = await Repo.fetchArticleItem(i);
    if (article != null) {
      articles.add(article);
    }
  }
  if (articles != null) {
    ctx.dispatch(ArticleListActionCreator.onSetArticles(articles));
  }
}
```

and in reducer change the state:

```
ArticleListState _onSetArticles(ArticleListState state, Action action) {
  ArticleListState newState = state.clone();
  List<Item> articles = (action.payload as List<Item>);
  newState.articles = articles;
  newState.articleRequest.latestTime = 1;
  return newState;
}
```

I think when return the newstate, the UI buildView should trigger the rerender,and the state may be the newest with article info. but the article info aways get null, and did not trigger rerender actuallly. what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should implement the connector set function like this:

```
 @override
  void set(HomeListDefaultState state, ArticleListState subState) {
    state.articleListState.articles = subState.articles;
  }
```